# Laravel Target class [TaskController] does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

Недавно вышла 8 версия Laravel.
Используя `composer global require laravel/installer` поставил последнюю версию Laravel.
Создаю контроллер используя `php artisan make:controller TaskContoller` и делаю ему стандартный метод `index`, который возвращает view `welcome`.
Прописал это всё в роут, но получаю ошибку

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [TaskController] does not exist.
```

TaskController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('welcome');
    }
}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', 'TaskController@index');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ответ с английского Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63807930/target-class-controller-does-not-exist-laravel-8)

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\TaskController;

Route::get('/', [TaskController::class, 'index']);
```